# How to integrate Tableau with React JS

Tags: reactjs

I am working on React.js. I want to know how to integrate tableau with React JS code. If you have any reference let me know

Thanks for Advance

Answer (score 2):

If you want to integrate your Tableau dashboard in your ReactJS application, you can either use the [Tableau JavaScript API](https://help.tableau.com/current/api/js_api/en-us/JavaScriptAPI/js_api.htm)

Add this inside your Index.html : `<script type="text/javascript" src="https://public.tableau.com/javascripts/api/tableau-2.min.js"></script>`

and create one component to render the dashboard as per the instructions
[here](https://help.tableau.com/current/api/js_api/en-us/JavaScriptAPI/js_api_sample_basic_embed.htm).

OR

use the [Tableau-React library](https://www.npmjs.com/package/tableau-react).

Comment: Is there any way to provide a sign-in access token so it should not ask for sign-in on third-party application??

@Tanya singh, Can you please help me.

Comment: @AditiSingh you need create a connected app and generate a token for your web client in order to avoid double sign-in

Answer (score 2):

Add:

```
 <script type="text/javascript" src="https://<tableauurl>/javascripts/api/tableau-2.min.js"></script>
```

then add:

```
const { tableau } = window;
  const url = "https://<tableau-dashboard-url>/views/testing/map";
  const ref = useRef(null)
  console.log(ref);
  function initViz(){
    new tableau.Viz(ref.current, url);
  }
useEffect(() => {
    initViz();
  },[])
```

And inside return, add below line:

```
<div ref={ref}></div>
```

It will work for sure :)

Answer (score 0):

Add this below code in index.html

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://public.tableau.com/javascripts/api/tableau-2.min.js"></script>
```

or

if you want to add private tableau data then add this

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://<PrivateTableauUrl>/javascripts/api/tableau-2.min.js"></script>
```

This in functional component

```
  const { tableau } = window;
  const url = "https://public.tableau.com/shared/GWK3297KY?:display_count=n&:origin=viz_share_link";
  const ref = useRef(null);
  let chartInstance;
  
  function initViz(){
   chartInstance = new tableau.Viz(ref.current, url);
  }

  useEffect(() => {
    initViz();
    return () => {
        if(chartInstance){ 
            chartInstance.dispose();
        }
      } 
  },[])
```

and this in return

```
<div ref={ref}></div>
```